# about AlphaBeta algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, chess

I have experienced AlphaBeta algorithm with my own old chess engine and now i am trying to write new engine and i see that algorithim encounter beta cut-offs but in my opinion, this should never be occur if i don't use narrowed window. Am i wrong ? I am using `int.MaxValue` for  beta and `-int.MaxValue` for alpha so what can cause a beta cut-offs ?

#### Edit:

Full code is here.

```
    public Result Search(int maxDepth)
    {
        int alpha = -int.MaxValue, beta = int.MaxValue, ply = maxDepth;
        var bestLine = new Stack<Move>();

        var score = AlphaBeta(alpha, beta, ply, bestLine);

        return new Result(score, bestLine);
    }
    int AlphaBeta(int alpha, int beta, int ply, Stack<Move> bestLine)
    {
        if (ply <= 0) return Evaluation.Evaluate(Board);
        var moves = Board.GenerateMoves();
        foreach (var move in moves)
        {
            Board.MakeMove(move);

            eval = -AlphaBeta(-beta, -alpha, ply - 1, bestLine);

            Board.TakeBackMove(move);

            if (eval >= beta)
            {
                return beta;
            }
            if (eval > alpha)
            {
                alpha = eval;
                if (ply == 1) bestLine.Clear();

                bestLine.Push(move);
            }
        }
        return alpha;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you are right on the MinValue/MaxValue thing.

<strike>I'm a bit rusty about NegaMax and AlphaBeta but when I see</strike>

```
   if (eval >= beta)
   {
       return beta;
   }
   if (eval > alpha)
   {
   }
```

You're testing `>` for both limits, that doesn't seem right.

Edit: It seems just a naming/understanding issue of sorts.  Your `AlphaBeta()` method could be named more accurately `NegaMaxWithAlphaBeta()`. Because of the alternating roles of alpha and beta in NegaMax the naming of those parameters is not an exact match with MiniMax.

> i see that algorithim encounter beta cut-offs but in my opinion, this should never occur

Yes it should occur. And it's only a beta-cutoff at the even ply-levels.  At the odd levels, `if (eval >= beta)` tests for an alpha-cutoff.

> if i don't use narrowed window.

I think you are using a narrowing alpha/beta window.

But maybe this answer can help you explain your problem better.

Comment: Articles about AlphaBeta  proves that it is not wrong. But really i will get crazy that where comes this mistake. do u also agree that never beta cut-offs should be ? Because it is full window search.

Comment: Back to basics - do you see _wrong_ beta-cutoff or don't you expect beta cutting at all? Ie is the line `return beta` being executed?

Comment: See for instance [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning), in the pseudocode there only is a beta-cut, no alpha...

Comment: Yes, return beta is executing and my assume that this should never been happen.

Comment: It's the point where alpha/beta __is helping__ ... You don't have an alpha cutoff, so if there was no `return beta` you might as well drop the whole pruning.

Comment: AlphaBeta algorithim is not easy as it looks. If there is no alpha return or beta, it means u use narrowed alpha and beta values. In full windows search(max values for alpha and beta) only alpha can return.

Comment: without the return beta, where else is your tree being pruned?

Comment: I hadn't understand this algorithm very well thats why my assumng wasn't right. I just confused it with aspiration window extension. I think this time u are right. I use AlphaBeta not MinMax so beta cut-offs occur. This is not bug. I think the problem is occur on collection principal variation so i will try to fix it. Thanks your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in your recursion you pass the parameters in reverse order:

```
eval = -AlphaBeta(-beta, -alpha, ply - 1, bestLine);
```

Reversed from the way they are declared:

```
int AlphaBeta(int alpha, int beta, int ply, Stack bestLine)
```

So they change roles at each ply. Alpha can be updated, and that's equivalent to a reduction in beta on deeper levels of the tree.

To me this looks like an odd mix of Alpha/Beta and Negamax since both players are trying to reduce the score, which is negated at each level.